# SQL- Fetch data from column3 even if the condition matches with column1 or column2

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two chained select boxes and two tables....I want user to select a value from first select box and then based on that select box i want to set options for second select box for which i am using ajax....

**Table1: Cat**

```
id      cat      scat      vid

1       Venue    Hotel     161
2       Venue    Hotel     162
1       Venue    Farms     163
2       Apparel  Mens      164
1       Apparel  Womens    165
2       Apparel  Kids      166
```

**Table2: Advert**

```
id      name     area

161     ABV      Ludhiana
162     BCD      Jalandhar
163     ABD      Delhi
164     ACD      Chennai
165     ASF      Delhi
166     ASh      Delhi
```

First select fetches DISTINCT cat and scat from table1 **"Cat"**. Which is working absolutely fine for me.

Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT scat from Cat 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT cat from Cat 
order by scat;
```

Now upon selecting a cat or scat from first select box i want to display area from table2 which matches the selected cat or scat...e.g. If user Selects "Venue" from first select "area" of "vid" 161 and 163 i.e. "Ludhiana" And "Delhi" to be fetched. And if user SELECTS "Hotel" then "area" of "vid" 161 and 162 Ludhiana and jalandhar to be displayed in second select box...

What query do i need to use ?? I tried a lot but could not reach to my solution...Thanks...

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT scat from cat` -- code smell :)

Comment: UNION already imply DISTINCT. You can remove both DISTINCT from your query

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Okay thanks for the point....i will keep it in my mind now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be this help you

```
declare @Value varchar(50)='Hotel'      
SELECT DISTINCT area FROM Advert 
WHERE id in (SELECT DISTINCT vid form cat where cat=@Value OR scat =@value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would avoid a `UNION` between `cat` and `scat` because they are presumably distinct types and instead `UNION` the results becuase they are definitely both of the same type `area`:

```
SELECT area
  FROM Cat
       NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT id AS vid, area FROM Advert ) A
 WHERE cat = 'Hotel'
UNION
SELECT area
  FROM Cat
       NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT id AS vid, area FROM Advert ) A
 WHERE scat = 'Hotel';
```

Replace the literal 'Hotel' with a parameter, of course.

Comment: Then how i can fetch both cat and scat in same field if i don't use UNION ??

Comment: @Ashish: With a union of the results, as shown in my answer.